# connection pool mechanism to connect to unix machine from java code

Tags: java, linux, unix, ssh, connection

I know that connection pool mechanism in database lets you keep database opened between many transactions and then close the database only at the end.
I am using the sshxcute(http://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/) to connect to unix machine from java code. but if i have to execute unix commands from different java files the entire process right from connecting to machine takes place. i want to keep the session open between many calls to this machine. how to acheive this. basically i want some some mechanism like connection pool which lets me open(connect) to unix machine only once and execute as many instructions as i want from different java classes or methods and finally once for all close the session/connection to the unix machine..

Comment: Do you really need a pool or could you just pass the SSHExec instance between your classes?

Comment: I am not sure if it works as those calls are generated from event listener methods in different java classes and how can i pass sshxcute instance from the listeners. well how can they get the same sshxcute instance in the first place..

Answer (score 0):

I've had to create such pools. It's not that hard. In a nutshell, my general approach is:

1. Create a class to manage the pool.
2. In that class, create a Collection to hold the available connections. (Ooh, nice rhyme to that.) Probably a LinkedList but it could be an ArrayList, etc. Create a second Collection to hold the connections that are currently in use. Initially these collections are empty.
3. Create a function in that class that can be called to request a connection. That function checks if there are any connections in the pool. If so, it picks one, removes it from the available collection, adds it to the used collection, and returns it to the caller. If not, it creates a new one, adds it to the used collection, and returns it the caller.
4. Create a function that can be called to release a connection. That functions takes the collection as a parameter, removes it from the used collection, and adds it to the available collection. (If it's not in the used collection, that means someone got a connection without going through the pool. You may want to add it to the available collection anyway, or just close it and throw it away.)

That's basically it. There are, of course, bunches of details to be considered. Like:

Should there be a limit on maximum number of connections? If so, you must keep count of how many connections you've given out, and if a new request would put you over that limit, throw an exception instead of returning a connection. (Or maybe return a null, depending on just how you want to handle it.)

Should there be a limit on the number of connections to keep in the available pool? If so, when a connection is released, instead of automatically adding it to the available pool, check if the pool is already at maximum size and if so, close the connection instead of returning it to the pool.

It's a good idea for the get-connection function to test a connection before returning it. It's possible that the connection has timed out while it was sitting in the pool, for example. Perhaps you can send some low-cost message and make sure you get a valid response.

The main reason for having a used collection is so you can watch for connection leaks, i.e. someone requests a connection and then never gives it back. Rather than putting the connection directly into the used collection, I usually create a wrapper object to hold it that also keeps the time that it was given out. Then I put in a function that is called with a timer that loops through the used collection and checks if there is anything that has been there for a ridiculously long amount of time. Depending on the type of connection, you may be able to check when it was last actually used or do some other test to see if the caller is really still using it or if it is a connection leak. If you're confidant that you can recognize a connection leak, you might close it or return it to the available pool. Otherwise you can at least write a message to a log, and periodically check the logs to see if you have leakage problems and hunt them down. If you don't do any connection-leak tracking, then the used collection is probably superfluous and can be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Several ideas here: 
A. Use an object pool. For example, you can use [this](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) one.  
This will let you hold a pool of several Unix connections.
B. Have some sort of session management at your application level, 
And have a session context which will hold a reference to an object taken from the pool. 
Once a session starts - you will try to obtain a connection from the pool. 
Once the session ends, you will return the connection to the pool. 
Bare in mind that you may not have a 1:1 ratio between your application sessions and the objects held at the pool. 
A possible strategy to handle this is to create a pool at initial size X, and let it grow up to size Y, if needed. 
Another issue that you will need to handle, is perhaps to have some sort of "keep alive" check to see that your connections are alive 
The two strategies I can think of here are: 
A. Have periodic check on connections (let's say - use ping). 
B. Create a new connection, if one of the connections at the pool got broken.